# How to update the type of an internal class prop based on a method

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a Class that can take an input of (so far) either SVGElements or HTMLElements or an array containing those. Now I want to strongly type it so that the method on that class let the person know what type it has based on what the user entered. This works fine if we know the type on initialization. Now however the class has a method that allows to add more elements after initialization and this is something I’m struggling to let typescript know about.

See this example:

```
type InputTypes = HTMLElement | SVGElement

function ensureArray<T>(input?: T | T[]): T[] {
  if(!input) return []
  return Array.isArray(input) ? input : [input];
}

class MyClass2<E extends InputTypes> {
  els?: E | [E]
  bar: E;
  constructor(m1: MyClass<E>) {
    this.els = m1.props.els
    const ensured = ensureArray<E>(this.els)
    this.bar = ensured[0]
  }
}

class MyClass<E extends InputTypes>{
  props: { els?: E | [E] }
  m2: MyClass2<E>
  constructor(props: { els?: E | [E] }) {
    this.props = props
    this.m2 = new MyClass2(this)
  }

  getBar() {
    return this.m2.bar
  }

  public setBar = (els: E | [E]) => {
    const ensured = ensureArray<E>(els)
    this.m2.bar = ensured[0]
  }
}

const element = document.getElementsByClassName("bla")[0]

var test1 = new MyClass({})
var foo1 = test1.getBar()
var bar1 = test1.setBar(element as HTMLElement)
var baz1 = test1.getBar() // Type is InputTypes instead of HTMLElement

var test2 = new MyClass({ els: element as HTMLElement })
var foo2 = test2.getBar()
var baz21 = test2.getBar() // HTMLElement, awesome, that is correct! but…
var bar2 = test2.setBar(element as SVGElement) // Type 'SVGElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement' …
var baz22 = test2.getBar()
```

As you can see, i.e. in `bar1` I’m adding an element of type HTMLElement. So I want `baz1` to reflect that the type is `HTMLElement` only instead of still (HTML or SVG).

Likewise, on the second test, I put in an HTMLElement on initialization, now TypeScript knows correctly that the elements inside are all of `HTMLElement` and tells me that baz21 is of type `HTMLElement`. Awesome! Unfortunately tho’ if I want to add another element of type `SVGElement` it complains that it does not match the `HTMLElement` type. Also baz22 is still of type `HTMLElement` although it should now be both `HTMLElement | SVGElement` since both types are in the array now.

So how can I update the types accordingly? Is this even possible to do in typescript?

Here is a [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAKuCBnKBeKAJFAWQBkBRAGwgFsI5goAfKAZQDUBxC624AKF4BmiOAGNgASwD2cKLQyIAThACCChQEMQAHhQA%20ABTiEyAPwAuKCkaWA2gF0AlBZT2oAb15Qo4gfoCERkjADlBKwIoy9p6hEOEKMqoaIAB04hiJmobGwVAm3tlQFjaByHYA3LwAvvwi5OoYWIQgAMJ1DQBMWqSyAB7AtAAmWPBBaJAYuu7REOQY5lDdTDakdtEARuoKFqQVXiLSGMAKiGKSCvpUAIwWTa31GF26IR5eXsAAFmnJM1i4V8lgBSSMAYb6zaJ7A70OSKCADHCyODyJQZbSkAwfL4-BwQqCY0EbBQImFKAY2AAMqy81WqvFq9ygtzaD26ED6g2G2TGmF0LyggOBGAsblks3miygyzsUGqXio7RuLWZnXR0X2SKOJ2AZ30ApBwtFc221ilMueuPxAKBIIReowFs%20oPlCLgEAA7oylfd2vp8TjqfwvABzWIAIU2%20nNrxicRklvlyUJ0VpXiQa3I4hEUAwYc2CP0P2NSxWIWwkz5kI1iORcOJSNhqMeBdm-te8faibzuBJcIpVJlVRqUNF3DoCIGkhEiBodGSIeAXBnwAwoa9DQAcuoaPoAETp9Q7hx9-gANzz-UOlxd7s9dwa%20jclRxZ6JAkkkivuAvwEuc9z52fPNCU-PFMB-ZIc2AcNzhmUd6HqfAiDISgl0AokNgALxA79f3naDIygAB6QjLHQbxOVGdAsCMQ4IHUeFJAERCSEXHhT3PMD2mvD0mXuB9DQsWClygBCCBYlCeDNXgXygN9JC4r9OL-KCIzQqBMPabClLw1TpKAzYFNAw4O0g-ChMkhC2E4CS6BCYjSMgKAAHIrNYugnPIqAqDSDAjCDPF3mgN9yHISQ3T8-lrQgBQJEwWSgSoPEyKcsTkLgjzADICPT0PUDD2kM78Ox0gCgA)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be possible, its impossible change generic after type defined. So, if you define a variable of type MyClass as MyClass, it allways be a MyClass type. Watch out when using genetics with unions, typescript(and others) cannot infer types in union, it need to be done by yourself.